# Standard Evaluation to calculate the mean using summarise()

Tags: r, dplyr

So I am taking a column name which is guaranteed to exist in the data frame as the input, and want to calculate the mean of the given column (Let's suppose c is the parameter in the function).

EDIT: Tried recreating a scenario here.

```
states <- c("Washington", "Washington", "California", "California")
random.data <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
data <- data.frame(states, random.data)

data.frame <- data %>%
              group_by(states) %>%
              summarise_(average = mean(paste0("random", ".data")))
```

When I tried doing this I got the following error:

```
Warning message:
In mean.default(paste0("random", ".data")) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

I have an idea about standard evaluation, but for some reason it is not working for this mean function.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  What is `c`?

Comment: I've tried reproducing a scenario in the edit, basically I am constructing a column name based on the input given to me, and want to pass that constructed column name to mean().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sym` with `!!`

```
col <- paste0("random", ".data")
data %>%
   group_by(states) %>% 
   summarise(average = mean(!! rlang::sym(col)))
   ##or use directly
   #summarise(average = mean(!! rlang::sym(paste0("random", ".data"))))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#      states average
#     <fctr>   <dbl>
#1 California      35
#2 Washington      15
```

---

Or another option is `get`

```
data %>%
    group_by(states) %>% 
    summarise(average = mean(get(paste0("random", ".data"))))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     states average
#      <fctr>   <dbl>
#1 California      35
#2 Washington      15
```

Comment: why not data %>%
  group_by(states) %>%
  summarise(average = mean(random.data))

Comment: @Mateusz1981  The OP wanted to pass it as a string or store it as another object

Comment: @Mateusz1981  It could be that the variable to summarise may be based on user input string